# Apply transition animation when mapped array changes state in react.js

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, setstate

I have these three images that are being mapped from state. When the next button is clicked, it removes the last image and adds it as the first element of the array.

Is it possible to animate this transition rather than it being snappy. I want it to slide to the right as the width and opacity are gradually changing, similar to a 3d carousel.

This is a codesandbox of what it currently looks like.
https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-cloud-z1j0jg?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To animate, you can use css transitions. However you'll probably have to keep some extra state to control when the animation has started or ended. This is not something that is very easy to do in React. Some libraries help you with this, such as react-spring, for example.

Comment: I was afraid that I was underestimating the complexity of the task and I guess I was. I ended up implementing it with react-slick and it was fairly straightforward. react-spring is look like an incredible package by the way, I'll play around with it and see if I can use it in future projects. Thanks!

Comment: once you do, remember please to accept the answer :)